# How to click on the Cancel button as per the html through Selenium and Java

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriver

HTML:

```
<button type="button" class="modal-footer-button g-capitalize btn btn link">Cancel</button>
```

Code trial:

```
By.xpath("//button[@type='button']").click()
```

didn't work.

Tried number of other ways too. Unable to click on Cancel button.
error:

> org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to
>   locate element:
>   {"method":"xpath","selector":"//button[@type='button'][@class='modal-footer-button
>   g-capitalize btn btn-link'][@value='Cancel']"}

Comment: What error you are getting? Share relevant HTML and exact code you tried.

Comment: Is the button inside `<frame>` tag?

Comment: Selector in provided code differs from the one in Exception log... Both of them *didn't work*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be a timing issue. Try to wait until required button appears in DOM:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);

wait.until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[@class='fade modal' and @role='dialog']")));
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//button[contains(@class, 'modal-footer-button') and text()='Cancel']"))).click();
```

Comment: This is the error , I am getting after modified as you suggested. org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Element <button type="button" class="modal-footer-button g-capitalize btn btn-link">...</button> is not clickable at point (537, 397). Other element would receive the click: <div role="dialog" tabindex="-1" class="fade modal" style="display: block;">...</div>

Comment: after "save" a dialog window pops up -> click "ok" -> back to old window with Cancel and Save. Focus is on Save and couldn't click on Cancel.

Comment: So the Cancel button is disabled? What is your current exception?

Comment: Cancel isn't disabled. it's there but focus is on Save.

Comment: How do you shift focus to dialog window. if , i don't do save and directly cancel, this is working. wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//button[contains(@class, 'modal-footer-button') and text()='Cancel']"))).click(); but, if I save and click ok , which returns to old dialog and try to click cancle, it doesn't work

Comment: So you do 1) Click "Save", 2) In opened modal click "OK", 3) After modal closed click "Cancel", right? And now on clicking Cancel you get TimeoutException or what?

Comment: i get this error: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Element <button type="button" class="modal-footer-button g-capitalize btn btn-link">...</button> is not clickable at point (537, 397). Other element would receive the click: <div role="dialog" tabindex="-1" class="fade modal" style="display: block;">...</div>

Comment: Did you try to add `wait.until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[@class='fade modal']")));` as in updated answer?

Comment: Hmm... Try more specific locator: `wait.until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[@class='fade modal' and @role='dialog']")));`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
WebElement Cancelbtn= driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[text()='Cancel']"));
Cancelbtn.click();
```

Also, place some wait till element to be located

```
driver.manage().window().maximize();    
WebElement Cancelbtn= driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[text()='Cancel']"));
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(Cancelbtn));
Cancelbtn.click();
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the *HTML* you have shared the element with *text* as **Cancel** is within a *Modal Window* so you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *element to be clickable* and you can use either of the following solution:

- `cssSelector`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("button.modal-footer-button.g-capitalize.btn.btn.link[type='button']"))).click();
  ```
- `xpath`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//button[@class='modal-footer-button g-capitalize btn btn link' and contains(.,'Cancel')]"))).click();
  ```

Comment: Modal window has Cancel and Save. After Save another window pops up -. click ok, returns to modal window. Now, click on Cancel failing. If , I do Cancel without save, the xpath is working.

Comment: You need to update this information within the question. What happens when you use this line of code?